# Issues migrating site back to local server

Tags: 7, database

I have issues migrating my Drupal 7.14 site from Live Server back to local. This might be more sql related, but not sure at this point where the error comes from. Might be specifically Acquia related.

The site is now perfectly running on the live server. I made some new nodes etc and now I wish to work more on the structure. I was trying to migrate it back to my local Acquia server by doing the following:

- creating local safety copy of the current local site (also to preserve the local settings.php file)
- creating safety copy of local sql db
- exporting live sql db, then dropping tables of local db and replacing them with the live one
- replacing local site files with the ones downloaded from live
- updating settings.php from the original local safety copy

What happens is:

- when trying to access local address (mysite:8082) I get 'could not find' error message. this comes from google, so the local drupal site doesn't even get recognized in any way
- i am still able to set up new Drupal installations via Acquia and they run perfectly
- if I replace the sql db of a newly installed site with the one I got from the live site I get the same error
- i can't seem to get the local site running even if I use the safety copy sql + safety copy of the local site
- if I go to a definite url such as 'mysite:8082/index' I get the following: "The requested URL /index was not found on this server."

Where should I look next? What could be in the sql that makes the whole server unrecognisable?Any completely different ways to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please check and let me know some details first: what is your OS (Windows, Linux etc.)? What is your local web server (apache, nginx etc.) ? I understand your database is MySql.  What do you see when accessing `http://mysite:80` ? `http://localhost` ?

Comment: this may not clear up all your problems, but make sure you've also copied the .htaccess file from live back to local.   some FTP clients miss "dot" files!

Comment: If you use the Acquia Drupal then you probably have the Acquia distribution based on Drupal 7.14, Apache, MySQL and PHP. Check your Apache (localhost) configuration first if you cannot connect via http.

Comment: @Refineo OS is Mac OSX 10.8.2. Acquia uses apache by default and database is mySql. if I access those addresses I just get redirected to google's 'Page not found' message.

Comment: @jdu i've been thinking about this. Mac seems to ignore/hide .htacess as I don't seem to be able to create it even manually. I will look into this (however a newly created local site works fine without it)

Comment: @Refineo oh i might have just found the relevant doc that Acquia provides on importing sites. It seems like the site needs to be registered through the desktop client as opposed to just updating the database+codebase back and forth. will leave it here, maybe someone needs it:

https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop/site/import

Comment: It's good you found the solution, now maybe you could use your last comment as an answer to your own question so that other users know it is already answered ?

Comment: @Refineo that's right, i will. i just have to wait cos i have low reputation. gotta wait 8 hours after posting

Answer (score 2):

As the OP noted in a comment, there is [documentation available from Aquia](http://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop/site/import) that explains how to do this. For a better formatted answer please follow the above link.

> IMPORTING AN EXISTING SITE OR CODEBASE INTO ACQUIA DEV DESKTOP
>
> To run an existing site or new Drupal distribution on your local
>   computer, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Ensure that your local computer contains a copy of your site's Drupal
>      files and directories (codebase).
>
>    - Save your site's codebase in a place where you can find it and where
>        you won't delete or move it unintentionally. This protects your site
>        from accidental removal, and helps when you need to modify site
>        content or change the installed modules.
>    - You cannot import zipped or compressed codebases into Dev Desktop.
>        Ensure that your site's code is uncompressed.
>    - For more information about backing up the Drupal file system, see
>        [Drupal file system backup](https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-drupal/appendix/back-up/files).
>
>    **Note:** Dev Desktop does not move or copy your site's code into the Dev
>      Desktop installation directory. Instead, Dev Desktop records where the
>      Drupal directories are stored on your local computer.
> 2. Open the Acquia Dev Desktop Control Panel, click **Settings**, and then
>      select the Sites tab.
> 3. Click **Import**. The Import site window opens.
> 4. In the Codebase section, click **Browse** to select the source code
>      directory (also known as [docroot]) of your Drupal installation. This
>      directory contains Drupal's files and directories, including
>      index.php, the /includes directory, and the /modules directory.
> 5. After you select the your codebase, in the **Subsite** drop-down menu,
>      select the site to import from the source code directory. For
>      single-site codebases or Drupal distributions, select default. If
>      you're importing a codebase that contains multiple subsites, select
>      the subsite you want to import from the Subsites drop-down menu.
>
>    **Note**: Dev Desktop can only import one site at a time.
> 6. Configure the database settings for the site import process. The
>      settings are based on the type of site or codebase you're importing
>      into Dev Desktop.
> 7. In the **Database name** field, enter a name for
>      the database. If you're restoring a backed up database, the name does
>      not have to match the backed up database's previous name.
> 8. Under **Domain**, enter the elements (server, subdomain, and URL path) of
>      the local URL you want to use for your site. For example, if you want
>      to reach your site locally at `http://my.example:8082/mysite`, enter my
>      for the **Subdomain**, `example` for the **Server**, and `mysite` for the URL
>      path. The subdomain and **URL path** are optional.
> 9. Click **Import**.
>
>    Acquia Dev Desktop records the location of your site's Drupal
>      codebase, creates its new database (if selected), and adds the site to
>      the list of sites in the Sites tab.